# Identity Server 4 - Role claims missing in OpenIdConnect handler in MVC client

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I know this issue has been reported alot and there are a lot of articles on how to fix this. I've gone through a lot of them and still can't solve this.

I am setting custom claims on the `Principal.Identity` from within the `OnSecurityTokenValidated` callback in Identity Server like so:

```
public async Task SecurityTokenValidated(SecurityTokenValidatedContext context) {
    var identity = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    foreach(var claim in context.Principal.Claims.Where(x = >x.Type == "adGroupClaimType").ToList()) {
        var groupName = Configuration.GetSection("ClaimMappings").GetValue < string > ($ "Prefix_{claim.Value}");
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(groupName)) {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, groupName));
        }

        identity.RemoveClaim(claim);
    }
}
```

The following is the configuration I use in Identity Server:

```
public static IEnumerable < IdentityResource > IdentityResources = >new List < IdentityResource > {
    new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
    new IdentityResources.Profile(),
    new IdentityResource("roles", new[] {
        ClaimTypes.Role
    })
};

public static IEnumerable < ApiScope > ApiScopes = >new List < ApiScope > {
    new ApiScope("api", "API")
};

public static IEnumerable < Client > Clients = >new List < Client > {
    new Client {
        ClientId = "mvc-openid",
        ClientSecrets = {
            new Secret("secret".Sha256())
        },
        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
        RedirectUris = {
            "https://localhost:6001/signin-oidc"
        },
        AllowedScopes = new List < string > {
            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
            "api",
            "roles"
        },
        RequirePkce = false,
        AllowOfflineAccess = true,
        AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true
    }
};
```

There's an MVC client which connects to the Identity Server using OpenIdConnect. The code is given below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddMvc();
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

    services.AddAuthentication(options = >{
        options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    }).AddCookie(options = >{
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = 15;
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.None;
    }).AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options = >{
        options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
        options.ClientId = "mvc-openid";
        options.ClientSecret = "secret";
        options.ResponseType = "code id_token token";
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.Scope.Add("api");
        options.Scope.Add("roles");
        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
        options.Events.OnTokenValidated = OnTokenValidated;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
            NameClaimType = ClaimTypes.Name,
            RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role
        };

        options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Role, ClaimTypes.Role);
    });
}

private Task OnTokenValidated(TokenValidatedContext context) {
    var t = context.Principal.Claims;
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

When I inspect the claims inside `OnTokenValidated`, I could see that all the role claims that I set from Identity Server are missing. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong? I have tried almost everything found on the Stack Overflow threads about this issue. Clueless right now as to what to do next.

Comment: add AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true to your client configuration and check 
this will add claims to your access_token

Comment: @mohammadmahdiTalachi Did that. It doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

I have also only found this solution so far.

```
options.Events.OnUserInformationReceived = context =>
{
    var roleElement = context.User.RootElement.GetProperty("role");

    var claims = new List<Claim>();
    if (roleElement.ValueKind == System.Text.Json.JsonValueKind.Array)
    {
        foreach (var r in roleElement.EnumerateArray())
            claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, r.GetString()));
    }
    else
    {
        claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, roleElement.GetString()));
    }

    var id = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    id.AddClaims(claims);

    return Task.CompletedTask;
};
```

https://github.com/skoruba/IdentityServer4.Admin/issues/109